# Android - setup multiple Firebase projects with different services within one application

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

How do I integrate two Firebase projects within one Android app, so that both will still work independently?

The background:
Within my company's app I was using until now some old Firebase project mainly for GCM purposes. Now the decision within my organization has changed and we decided to move most of the services to the new Firebase project, with higher pricing plan - unfortunately the upgrade wasn't an option.

At this very moment I have:

- a legacy project for Cloud Messaging stuff related to some marketing service,
- a new Firebase project that will be used for Crashlytics, Remote Config flags and some more.

We don't want to move with Cloud Messaging due to the restrictions the switch causes - all the users would need to register to new notifications channel again. For Marketing reasons that's something unacceptable.

For now I was trying to use the new project's `JSON` configuration file initialized automagically by Gradle plugin and manual approach to register to the legacy FCM service like this:

```
FirebaseOptions fo = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setApplicationId(appId) 
        .setApiKey(apiKey)
        .setGcmSenderId(legacySenderId)
        .build();
FirebaseApp firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, fo, "legacy");

HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("getLegacyTokenThread");
thread.start();
Handler handler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());
handler.post(() -> {
    try {
        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(firebaseApp).getToken(legacySenderId, "FCM");
        L.w("Received token: " + token);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

But this approach seems to be **overriding my default project configuration**, so the exceptions are not reported to Crashlytics belonging to the new project.

Can anyone suggest how do I make it to run both projects successfully?

Comment: To access backend services from multiple Firebase projects in a single app, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application

Comment: @Frank I was following this guideline - as you can see, I'm passing to the builder the `GcmSenderId` value - and I am able to get the notifications from the _old project_, but the new one get somehow inactive. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure you can use two `GcmSenderId` values in a single project. I think there was a question about that a while ago, but can't find it right now. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Frank's comment above, I didn't manage to make this kind of integration successful.

We ended up in creating a new app in the marketing service that is using new credentials instead of changing the previous ones, what would result in invalidation of the integration. This way we can target both old app's users who didn't update as well as the new ones.